# Writing a simple custom read more on click function for jquery that needs refactoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, refactoring, css-selectors

I want to be able to reuse the same function many times on one page..

So here's some psuedo-code :

```
$(".read_more").click(function(){
$(this).parents().find(".hidden_text").slideToggle("fast")
});
```

The problem with this code, however, is that it targets every elem on the page matching .hidden_text. Is there a way to combine closest() with this? Or is there a better way to refactor this?

**Update:**

HTML:

```
<div class="grid_2">
  <div class="read_more">
    Click Me
  </div>
</div>

<div class="grid_2">
  <div id=".hidden_text">
    Bagels are the most resourceful tools to the most legendary programmers.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does the relevant HTML look like?  Which ".hidden_text" elements do you **want** to affect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think

```
$(this).closest("*:has(.hidden_text)").find(".hidden_text").slideToggle("fast");
```

will work.

Answer (score 1):

if the hidden content is at the same level that your read more link, ie:

```
<div>
    blbalbblal allalfdk 
    <a class="readmore">read more</a>
    <div class="hidden-text" style="display:none">other bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Then you can use the [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/) selector

```
   $(".readmore").click(function(){
        $(this).next(".hidden_text").slideToggle("fast")
    });
```

Comment: You may want to adjust your selector in your js. `$(".readmore")` or change your html to `class="read_more"` so your examples match up. :)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add 'return false' to stop jumping

```
$(".read_more").click(function(){
    $(this).next(".hidden_text").slideToggle("fast");
    return false;
});
```

And obviously add to css

```
.hidden_text {
    display:none
}
```